# Trying to run Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, pip

I am trying to run Scrapy and encountering the following error.

It seems that Scrapy can't find TheTwisted 10.0.0 - I've downloaded it but don't know where to place the folder. Thanks!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 5, in 
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 3095, in 
    @_call_aside
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 3081, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 3108, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 658, in _build_master
    ws.require(**requires**)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 959, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 846, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'Twisted>=10.0.0' distribution was not found and is required by Scrapy

Answer (score 0):

If using Linux, install Twisted by running `pip install Twisted` in terminal.

If Windows, the [Twisted docs recommend](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads) `pip install Twisted[windows_platform]`.

In both cases if you're using a virtual environment (recommended) make sure to install it inside the venv.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using OSX. 

I've tried that and get the following:

Requirement already satisfied: Twisted in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: zope.interface>=3.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Twisted)

etc.

Then, I try running Scrapy again and get the original error

Comment: Are you using a virtual env?